# excel 2016 autoupdates from one workbook to other (emailed) workbooks

Tags: microsoft-excel, auto-updates

I have this same question. I want to send a workbook to my collogues (each worksheet will be locked/protected) and I will keep the master (unprotected). When I make a change(s) how can all the other workbooks be automatically updated to show that change(s)? A pivot table will not work for me. I need all books to be updated as I make changes (prefer w/o sending new books every time a change is made)?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like what you need to do is use a cloud solution, something like Google Sheets or Microsoft's version of Office 365 in the cloud. You just create the document there and share a link to the document with your collaborators.

After creating a document and sharing it with your collaborators, you can see the edits they make and they can see yours. You can also set permissions on a per-sheet level, so if you want your collaborators to be able to see a certain sheet but not edit it, that is possible.

Comment: I don't know anything about that, only excel. I believe we just converted to Office 365, can you provide steps please?

Comment: It is not possible to have simultaneous editing with normal Excel files. If you must use the desktop version of Excel, you will have to provide each of your collaborators with new copies of the workbook whenever you make a change.

Comment: That's ok as long as the cloud has the ability to calculate a formula like "VLOOKUP", and have the simultaneous sharing when one file is updated.

Comment: Google sheets supports nearly all Excel functions and is free. Microsoft Office 365's Cloud version of Excel is just a port of desktop Excel in the browser and has almost all the functions Excel has. `VLOOKUP()` is one that is included in both!

Comment: Sweet! Just to make sure I am on the same page as you: When I complete the document in google sheets and then share it to whomever, when I update that shared sheet it will automatically update all sheets sent also. Correct?

Comment: Google sheets formulas are not working as well as excel. They cannot find things excel can, resulting in an incomplete worksheet, how do I try office 365 excel?